# how to pass driver to testng listeners

Tags: testng, listener

I have two class one with test method and other one is Listener class. I am closing browser onTestFailure in listener, for this i need to pass driver from test method to listener. How can I pass driver to onTestFailure method in listener. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The one which closes the browser/driver should be the one which created it too.

What you can do is:

1. In the listener: Create the driver
2. In the listener: Push the driver into the `ITestContext`
3. In the test class: Take the driver from the `ITestContext` and use it
4. In the listener: Close the browser/driver

Comment: Thanks Julien, you help was so valuable.